# Plug.Router.InvalidSpecError when running tests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working my way through Phoenix for Rails Developers and I'm running into an issue when testing. When I run `mix test` I receive the following error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/storex_web/router.ex ==
   ** (Plug.Router.InvalidSpecError) :identifier in routes must be made of letters, numbers and underscores
    (plug) lib/plug/router/utils.ex:193: Plug.Router.Utils.binary_to_identifier/2
    (plug) lib/plug/router/utils.ex:156: Plug.Router.Utils.segment_match/3
    (plug) lib/plug/router/utils.ex:120: Plug.Router.Utils.build_path_match/4
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:65: Phoenix.Router.Route.build_path_and_binding/1
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router/route.ex:50: Phoenix.Router.Route.exprs/1
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:320: anonymous fn/1 in Phoenix.Router."MACRO-__before_compile__"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1294: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1294: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
```

The relevant part of my router.ex file looks like this:

```
  scope "/", StorexWeb do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", BookController, :index
    get "/books/:id", BookController, :show

    resources "/carts", CartController, singleton: true, only: [:show, :create, :delete]
  end
```

I know the error is coming from the `/books/:id` line because `mix test` does not throw the error when I comment out that line. The route seems to be set up correctly because when I run `mix phx.server`, I can visit that route with no problems. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's strange. If it's a compile error the app shouldn't start at all with `mix phx.server`. Can you try clearing the cache and recompiling the app? `mix do clean, compile`.

Comment: That did not seem to change anything. `mix test` still throws an error, and `mix phx.server` still seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't know what `mix do clean` is supposed to do, but I just deleted the `_build/test` directory and that seemed to clean up whatever was dorked. `mix test` now runs without errors.